# Laravel pagination is not working after deploying it on AWS EC2 Sever

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, nginx, amazon-aurora

Laravel pagination not working properly after deploying the app on AWS EC2 server. It was working fine on the localhost using Xampp server. In the localhost, MySQL was used as the database whereas in AWS server Aurora MySQL database is used. It is basically a reporting page were the first page loads properly but whenever any other page is clicked from the below pagination links it shows loading for a long time then fails with the message "This site can’t be reached". In the AWS EC2 server, Nginx is used. Can anyone help me solving this issue?

Thank you

Comment: Check both laravel and nginx logs, they provide details about the error.

Comment: Already checked both the logs. There is no footprint of the error.

Comment: It could be that the hrefs that are generated do not point to the right domain. So when you click on them (page 2 button) you are sent to a bad url. Did you set the `APP_URL` env variable?

Comment: APP_URL is set to `APP_URL=http://localhost`

Comment: Well, shouldn't your APP_URL be the URL to the production server? ......

Comment: I tried putting the production server URL as well. Didn't make any change in this regard.

Comment: On your production server, the APP_URL should be the URL of the production server

Answer (score 1):

I have found out the solution of the problem. The pagination pages were not **https**. As a result, it was not supporting. I used forced https which was working perfectly for other URLs but was not working for paginations. I used `$users->setPath('');` after each paginate command to make those URL https. After taking the above-mentioned step, it worked properly. Thank you